# Facade goes inside in each package or must have a package only for facades?

Tags: design-patterns, facade

Where the Facade classes must go? Supposing I have three packages, Facade A goes inside Package A, Facade B goes inside Package B and Facade C goes inside Package C or I need a separate package only for Facades?

What is more recommended?

I'm using the first solution, but I think is not right. Some classes are using a facade that allocates some objects that the class not uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how your packages are organized.

Suppose you have `payment`, `hr` and `contacts` packages, then it would make sense to have a façade for each of them.

If you split your package in a less domain driven way, like for example `services`, `dao` and `web` then making a facade only for the service layer would make sense.

Comment: Example: I have a class that get some statistics. A part comes from the database package and the other from a processing package. I was using two facades to get all statistics. Now I have merged the method for statistics in a only facade in a separate packege for facades. Looks better now. HEHE

Comment: My system looks like a mix of the two examples. Using a separate facade package appears to be better now.